# Efficient way to return Array[String] from a spark dataframe without using collect()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to return `child` as an `Array[String]` from the below dataframe

```
root
     |-- parent: string (nullable = false)
     |-- child: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am doing this currently which does work for less data

```
df.collect().flatMap(x => x.getAs[Seq[String]]("child")).mkString(",")
```

but there are is a lot of data and spark driver is running `Out Of Memory` as `collect()` is known to do that.

What is efficient way to return array of Strings from the above dataframe?

Comment: why do you need to collect an array with the driver?, you can do the flatmap to the dataframe without collecting and destroying the driver

Comment: only doing this `cSNHdf.flatMap(x => x.getAs[Seq[String]]("childsn"))` does not work @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 0):

With the flatMap like:

```
df.flatMap(x => x.getAs[Seq[String]]("childsn")).show()
```

you will explode the children into a new string column:

```
/*
+-------+
|  value|
+-------+
|child_1|
|child_2|
+-------+
*/
```

if you need to create another column with the children separated by comma:

```
df.flatMap(x => Seq(x.getAs[Seq[String]]("childsn").mkString(","))).show()
```

it gives:

```
/*
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|child_1,child_2|
+---------------+
*/
```

Comment: `com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Error evaluating method : '<init>': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid argument count: expected 2, received 1`

I get this error.
and I want to return as an Array[String] and not a df

Comment: That error is related to how you are debugging your code with Intellij. Nothing related to Spark/Scla

Comment: this code would still give me dataframe with Array[String] and not an Array[String] by itself without dataframe. I want just a Array[String] not a dataframe.

Comment: Why do you need an array?, what do you want to do with it?. There is no sense in using Spark to process a big file and then collecting in the memory of a single machine, unless you apply some kind of reduction or to show any kind of statistics or metric or apply an algorithm that can not be distributed.

Comment: I need an array because the function which accepts output from this function takes array as an input and that function cannot be changed by me.